# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 OR how to get HDD space all the time

Tags: php, size, hard-drive

```
$harddrive_out = format_bytes(kb2bytes($harddrive[2])).'<small> / '.format_bytes(kb2bytes($harddrive[1])).' <small>('.calculate_percentage(kb2bytes($harddrive[2]), kb2bytes($harddrive[1])).'% Free)</small></small>';
```

This line gives me that error

I got this code from http://www.installgentoo.net/
it obviously works for them. I am using windows, and they are probably using linux

If this is a windows problem, how could I make something that works for windows AND linux (That always gets the correct HDD, so I don't use something like `disk_total_space("C:")` because all webservers might not have it on the C drive.

In case you want the methods I'm using

```
function format_bytes($bytes){ 
    if ($bytes < 1024){ return $bytes; } 
    else if ($bytes < 1048576){ return round($bytes / 1024, 2).'KB'; } 
    else if ($bytes < 1073741824){ return round($bytes / 1048576, 2).'MB'; } 
    else if ($bytes < 1099511627776){ return round($bytes / 1073741824, 2).'GB'; } 
    else{ return round($bytes / 1099511627776, 2).'TB'; } 
} 


    function kb2bytes($kb){ 
    return round($kb * 1024, 2); 
} 

function calculate_percentage($used, $total){ 
    return @round(100 - $used / $total * 100, 2);
```

Comment: I wonder how you want to decide _which_ parition you want to use / show. Typical servers have mounted several partitions in their file system (wrongly called 'disks' in MS-Windows-speek).

Comment: What is `$harddrive`? It appears to be an array, and indexing into `$harddisk[2]` would seem to be what's causing the problem. So how is `$harddrive` declared? How is it filled?

Comment: I want it to get ALL partitions

Comment: a "notice" is not an "error"

Comment: $harddrive = explode(' ', preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', exec('df /dev/xvda1')));

Comment: Well I still want to remove the notice

Comment: I doubt the `df` utility is available on any non-unixoid system.

Comment: @arkascha that is probably it. is there a way to make it work for windows, or a windows version. also ability to make it check if its windows to use it

Comment: non-unixoid .. aha ;)

Comment: You will have to implement a switch to use a different approach for each oeprating system type. MS-Windows systems are notoriously limited when it comes to easy usable command line utilities. There is that addition called "PowerShell", but the name is like a joke as is the shell it implements. MS-Windows simply is a very platform for server usage. Most likely you will have to do different things for different Windows versions too. I don't see a common solution for this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The Notice informs you that in

```
 $harddrive[2]
```

**2** is not a valid index.

So try checking by:

```
if(isset($harddrive[2])) // do your magic with that...
```